# Input validation for only alphabetical characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to validate my username input box that does not allows any number or special characters inside.
My Html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="display_name" class="form-control input-lg"
  placeholder="User Name" tabindex="3">
</div>
```

Javascript Validation

```
username: {
  required: true,
  minlength: 5,
  maxlength: 15,
  remote: "ajax_val/val_username.php",
  notNumber: true 
 },
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mefirocuti/1/)**

and if you dont want to use Regex then here is one approach:

```
function allowLetters(e, t) {
  try {
    if (window.event) {
      var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
    }
    else if (e) {
      var charCode = e.which;
    }
    else { return true; }
    return charCode > 64 && charCode < 91 || charCode > 96 && charCode < 123;
  }
  catch (err) {
    alert(err.Description);
  }
}
```

---

Here is one approach for HTML5 pattern attribute:

```
<form> 
    <input type='text' pattern='[A-Za-z\\s]*'/> 
</form>
```

Comment: Rahul can you show me how i can use this regex in my javascript validation

Comment: what if they c/p a number...? (for the function without the regex)

Comment: @Lina:- Updated the answer with the DEMO. Hope that helps now :)

Comment: So the only way is i have to make it a function i can not validate as i did for all of my form?

Comment: @Lina:- I am not sure what you are looking for but you can use the HTML5 pattern attribute `<form>
    <input type='text' pattern='[A-Za-z\\s]*'/>
</form>`

Comment: I don't think this works that well, i c/p a number and was able to hold down the enter button and it submitted just fine and the number appeared in the url. You might want to tighten up the expression.

Comment: The pattern attribute is cool, but has less support than the [oninput event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) (which only requires IE9+). Then again if you're alright with validating on form submission, the `<form>` element's [onsubmit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) has complete compatibility. Also, you can reduce the amount of code by changing the final if/else to `return charCode > 64 && charCode < 91 || charCode > 96 && charCode < 123;`

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at regex something like `[A-Za-z]+`.

This may be helpful: (or any other guide on RegExp's on the internet)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions